# R - plotting points on the same plot in for loop

Tags: r

```
lambda <- runif(10,min=0,max=3)
mean(lambda)
for (i in 1:10){
   N <- rpois(i,mean(lambda))
   mean(N)
   plot(i,mean(N))
}
```

Hi all, this is a really simple R code block I have here. I am basically trying to create a plot where I can see how the mean of the poisson distribution is changing as I increase its iteration using the rpois function. I would like to post these values (mean(N)) all on the same graph so I can see the change but I am not quite sure how to do that.

I have been googling a lot and I came across qqplot or so but I just started using R few days ago and I have having a lot of trouble.

Any insights would be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `points` function once a `plot` has been called:

```
lambda <- runif(10,min=0,max=3)
mean(lambda)

## First plot
N <- rpois(1,mean(lambda))
plot(1,mean(N), xlim = c(1,10))

## Subsequent points
for (i in 2:10){
   N <- rpois(i,mean(lambda))
   points(i,mean(N))
}
```

Comment: `points` will plot a single point. `lines`... a line. See their respective documentation for details.